# simultaneous change in session variables in two pages

Tags: php

Let's say we have two pages A, and B that both use/set the same session variable. These pages are called via AJAX so it's possible that they run simultaneously for the same user.
My question is, if page A changes the session variable, does page B observe the new value right after the change?

Answer (score 1):

No, page B would have to poll for the change.

Comment: Do you mean that page B should be refreshed?

Comment: Either refreshed or an AJAX call that retrieved the new value.

Answer (score 0):

The first request that gets handled by PHP will lock the session file, and any concurrent request for the same session will have to wait for the first request to release the lock.

So, yes, AJAX calls on the second page will get the updated data, if they are initiated after the first request.

Comment: Oh, I guess I didn't make myself clear enough. So assume that pages A and B are both running. Page A changes the session variable and a microsecond later, page B uses that variable. Does page B get the new or old value?

Comment: If you mean by "page B uses that variable" that a new request is made to the server (load/refresh/ajax), then yes, it will get the new value. The second request will take longer as it has to wait for the first to finish, then the server-side script will have access to the updated session variable.